# Convert DataFrame column date from 2/3/2007 format to 20070223 with python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataframe with 'Date' and 'Value', where the Date is in format m/d/yyyy.  I need to convert to yyyymmdd.

```
df2= df[["Date", "Transaction"]]
```

I know datetime can do this for me, but I can't get it to accept my format.

example data files:

```
6/15/2006,-4.27,
6/16/2006,-2.27,
6/19/2006,-6.35,
```

Answer (score 3):

You first need to convert to `datetime`, using `pd.datetime`, then you can format it as you wish using `strftime`:

```
>>> df
        Date  Transaction
0  6/15/2006        -4.27
1  6/16/2006        -2.27
2  6/19/2006        -6.35

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

>>> df
       Date  Transaction
0  20060615        -4.27
1  20060616        -2.27
2  20060619        -6.35
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

`dt` accesor's `strftime` method is your clear friend now.

Note: if didn't convert to pandas datetime yet, do:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Output:

```
       Date  Transaction
0  20060615        -4.27
1  20060616        -2.27
2  20060619        -6.35
```

Answer (score 0):

For a raw python solution, you could try something along the following (assuming datafile is a string).

```
datafile="6/15/2006,-4.27,\n6/16/2006,-2.27,\n6/19/2006,-6.35"

def zeroPad(str, desiredLen):
        while (len(str) < desiredLen):
                str = "0" + str
        return str

def convToYYYYMMDD(datafile):
        datafile = ''.join(datafile.split('\n')) # remove \n's, they're unreliable and not needed
        datafile = datafile.split(',') # split by comma so '1,2' becomes ['1','2']

        out = []

        for i in range(0, len(datafile)):
                if (i % 2 == 0):
                        tmp = datafile[i].split('/')
                        yyyymmdd = zeroPad(tmp[2], 4) + zeroPad(tmp[0], 2) + zeroPad(tmp[1], 2)
                        out.append(yyyymmdd)
                else:
                        out.append(datafile[i])

        return out

print(convToYYYYMMDD(datafile))
```

This outputs: `['20060615', '-4.27', '20060616', '-2.27', '20060619', '-6.35']`.